# Update subdocument MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

Using MongoDB in PHP, what would be the correct way to have document T1 contain T1_MODULE and T2_MODULE after running an update?  Doing this results in tools>T1>T2_MODULE with T1_MODULE removed.

```
$updater['tools']['T1']['T2_MODULE']=$update_array;
$this->db->user->updateOne(array("_id"=>$id),array('$set'=>$updater));

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a674bfa5cecc20bd660d43"),      
    "something" : [
        {
            "else" : NumberInt(1)
        }
    ], 
    "another_thing" : {        
        "further_disclosure" : ""
    }, 
    "tools" : {
        "T1" : {
            "T1_MODULE" : {
                "a" : "x", 
                "b" : "y"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer - use dot notation instead:

```
$updater['tools.T1.T2_MODULE']=$update_array;
```